# node.js - templates / rendering -- how can I exclude or specify an alternate layout.mustache for one of my views?

Tags: node.js, templates, express, connect, mustache

Currently all pages are rendered from a `views/layout.mustache` file and a page-specific   `views/page.mustache` template

I want to use an alternate `layout.mustache` and/or skip the `layout.mustache` all-together when rendering a certain view within my application.  What is the ideal way to go about doing this?

Here's a snippet of my `app.configure`:

```
app.configure(function(){
    ...
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.register(".mustache", require('stache'));
    ...
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of express are you using? With v3.0 the concept of layouts was [removed](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x).

V3.0 introduces the concept of [blocks](http://www.devthought.com/code/use-jade-blocks-not-layouts/). I don't use `mustache` but an example with jade looks like this:

```
// my-template.jade
extends my-layout

block head
  script(src="myfile.js")

block content
  h1 My page
```

and

```
// my-layout.jade
doctype 5
html
  head
    title My title
    block head
  body
    #content
      block content
```

With `extends` you can choose whatever "parent" layout you want. An overview of supported template engines is in the express [wiki](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki).

In express versions before 3.0 you could specify the layout when rendering

```
res.render('index', {
  title : 'Page with distinct layout', 
  layout : 'layout.mustache'
});
```

or disable layouts for certain views

```
res.render('start', {
  title : 'Page without layout', 
  layout : false
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, we're running 2.x though.  There's gotta be a basic way to do this.  Cheers.

Comment: I added examples for express 2.x. Hope they help!